# Xcode開発したアプリが実機(iphone)でテスト出来ません。

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

Xcode開発したアプリが実機でテストが出来ません。

複数人でXcodeを使用したアプリを開発しています。
ソースコードはgitで管理して、各々のMacにクローンしてきています。
Gitの管理者は実機(iPhone)テストができていますが、他のメンバーは「Build failed」となってしまいます。(有線でMacとiPhoneを繋いでいます)
Mac上でのシミュレーターでは問題なくビルド出来ています。

Appstoreで公開する予定がないので、Developer Programに登録はしていません。

なぜでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

`Build failed`になっている箇所があるはずなので、そのエラー文を読みましょう。
予想としては、`Signig & Capabilities`のTeamが選択されていないとかでしょうか

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
再度エラー文を確認してみます。

Signig & CapabilitiesのTeamは選択しているのですが、各々のAppleIDを設定しています。
共通のAppleIDではないといけないなどルールはございますか？

Comment: 共通のApple IDである必要はないですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。各メンバーに改めて状況を確認したいと思います。
五月雨式に申し訳ないのですが、有料のDeveloper programへの登録が必須条件ということはありますか？

Comment: それもないはずですね。